# What is the expectation and variance of non-negative sum of k random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, expected-value

Suppose I have $k$ random variables $X_i, i=1,2,...,k$ sampled independently from a certain distribution with expectation $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Now I compute $C$ as follow:

Initially $C=0$, at each round $i$,  $C \leftarrow \max(C+X_i, 0)$

Now After $k$ rounds of computation, what is $C$'s expectation and variance? How can I measure it?

If I can't measure it exactly, what is the empirical error for C compare with the expectation of ($\sum^k_i X_i$).

Comment: This looks like a $G/G/1$ queue.

Comment: You don't need the case distinction; you could just say $C\leftarrow\max(C+X_i,0)$, since this is also valid if $X_i\ge0$. Also, note that writing an assignment like $C\leftarrow C+X$ with an equals sign is misleading, since the symbol $C$ stands for different quantities on the two sides so that the equation is not valid under the usual interpretation of the symbol.